# How to DeSelect a cell in CellList Gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have a CellList in GWT, i need to deselect the cell when one link is clicked without using the selectionchange handler.Can someone help in this situation.

```
CellList<MyClass> cellList;    
SingleSelectionModel<MyClass> lSelectionModel;

final SingleSelectionModel<MyClass> lSelectionModel = 
    new SingleSelectionModel<MyClass>();
this.cellList.setSelectionModel(lSelectionModel);

public void setSelected(final MyClass pClass) {

        Anchor lLink = new Anchor();
        lLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent pEvent) {
        //Here i need to deselect the cell(Myclass)

            }
        });
```

}

Thanks in advance,

Raj

Comment: Can you please show us some code ?

Comment: @Baadshah i have added some sample code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `SingleSelectionModel`, is as easy as:

```
lLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent pEvent) {
    MyClass selected = lSelectionModel.getSelectedObject();
    if (selected != null) {
      lSelectionModel.setSelected(selected, false); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this, its working fine, but if i use this way some other functionality is afecting in my app, b'coz of my code.Is ther any other way to deselect the selected cell alone.

Comment: This is the right way to deselect ( it handles both ui and selection policy of mouse and keyboard )